# Why does Snowflake not read certain values?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm having trouble with our Snowflake database.  I'm simply trying to multiply a value by a constant (for certain rows) such as:

```
 select *,
 case when code = 'C' then answer *0.39 
 else answer end as answer_iu
 from rawheight
 where country in ('US')
```

The error I get is:

> Numeric value '171240156932559' is not recognized

It works fine when country is not 'US'.  It also works fine when the "case when" is eliminated ie:

```
 select *
 from rawheight
 where country in ('US')
```

I get the same error when I try to filter the table as well:

```
select *
from rawheight
where answer>1000
```

Any ideas of a workaround?

Comment: Try casting the answer column as integer or appropriate data type in your case expression and/or where statement.

Comment: Please update your question with the ddl for your table and some sample data

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes snowflake moves the order operations for VARAINT/JSON around, so while this code "should be safe" and actually does run correctly:

```
with raw_json as (
    select 
        parse_json('[
        {"code":"A", "answer":"171240156932559", "country":"US"},\
        {"code":"C", "answer":1000, "country":"NZ"},\
        {"code":"C", "answer":2000, "country":"US"}\
        ]') as json
), rawheight(code, country, answer) as (
    select 
        j.value:code,
        j.value:country,
        j.value:answer
    from raw_json as rj, 
    table(flatten(input=>rj.json)) as j
)
select *,
 case 
     when code = 'C' then answer * 0.39 
     else answer 
end as answer_iu
from rawheight
where country in ('US')
```

[image]

The optimizer can push the math/cast prior to filters that would remove rows that "do not apply", thus explosion's.

The standard way around this is to wrap data that is of many types number/float/string in VARIANT data with a TRY_TO_DOBULE or TRY_TO_FLOAT like:

```
TRY_TO_DOUBLE(answer) * 0.39
```

but that then gets upset, as that is not a text, so you have to cast to `::TEXT`

```
when code = 'C' then TRY_TO_DOUBLE(answer::TEXT) * 0.39
```

This now works safely for the class of processing I am describing.